# Spatial Join Layer Derived from Zonal Raster on Original Polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, spatial-analyst, spatial-join

I'm trying to do a 1:1 spatial join between polygons created from the zonal max of a slope raster on the original zonal features. The problem is that the jagged edges cause the target features to overlap neighboring polygons as well so it just uses the first join feature in the 1:1 join.

[image: Example]

So basically, in this picture, I want to use a spatial join to add the grid code 300 from the blue layer to the polygon (red outline) on the right and 100 to the polygon on the left. The overlap from the jagged lines are causing it to assign whichever value is first instead of whichever one has the greatest overlap.

Comment: Back in the old days we called this CREATELABELS/IDENTITY/IDENTITY, but Dale now calls this [Spaghetti and Meatballs analysis](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/13/spaghetti_and_meatballs/) there was a [follow-on blog post as well](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/26/spaghetti_meatballs_one_to_many/)

Comment: Can't you just do a tabular join? Zonal Statistics as Table preserves the Ids in the output table so they can be joined back to the original. That is the way I always do this.

Comment: I just ended up creating a new unique id and doing a tabular join. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a temporary unique id and doing a tabular join (Join Field) between the table I created via zonal statistics and the original polygon layer.

Answer (score 0):

In the screen shot you have given I think this can be easily done with a spatial join. You just need to set the match option to HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN. Be mindful that if you have tortuous shapes with holes in then this may fail for those scenarios.